# Left sidebar div does not move up in my HTML layout

Tags: html, css

I can't fix this gap issue right now. I have attached a screenshot below and also HTML and CSS code.

I tried many times and found it on youtube and StackOverflow, but I can't find anything like this.

The red X highlights the space where the left div should move to:

[image: Please take a look here]

```css
*{
    margin: 0%;
}
body{
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}



/* head div start */
.head{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
.headelement{
    background-color: rgb(115, 182, 240);
    height: auto;
}
/* head div end */



/* Left Side Bar Start */
.leftsidebar{
    display: flex;
}
.leftdiv{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
.leftelement{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(213, 233, 233);   
}
/* Left Side Bar end */



/* welcome div start  */
.welcomeDiv{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
.welcomeelement{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(193, 45, 196);
}
/* welcome div end  */



/* Inner 2 div start */
.innerdiv{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
.innerelement1{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(65, 225, 37); 
}
.innerelement2{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(226, 108, 23);
}
/* Inner 2 div end */



/* Footer div start */
.footerdiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.footerelement{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(132, 113, 122);
}
/* Footer div end */
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="head">
            <div class="headelement">
                <h1>Head Div</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftsidebar">
        <div class="leftdiv">
            <div class="leftelement"> <h1>Left Div</h1></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="welcomeDiv">
        <div class="welcomeelement"> 
            <h1>Welcome Div</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <div class="innerelement1">
            <h1>Inner no.1 div</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="innerelement2">
            <h1>Inner no.2 div</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerdiv">
        <div class="footerelement">
            <h1>Footer full width div </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no red box when you run your code snippet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your review. Please pardon me, and I didn't mean that. The red box in the screenshot.

Comment: This gap is on the top of "Left Div."

Comment: The left div width will be 20%, and the Head div width will be 80%. But the main problem is, I cant arrange them well.

Comment: Updated your question - I hope this is what you wanted to ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `head` div has a width of 100% with a margin of 20% but it still is in the way of the other element. I could also see this in the Chrome DevTools by selecting the element:

[image]

[image]

Changing the properties on the right did not change the layout.

If the `leftsidebar` div should move up, you must place it before the other HTML so there is space and it can move up.

The other elements will "auto-magically" arrange themselves around the `leftsidebar` div. I say magically because I haven't checked all your code regarding flex boxes and positioning.

Rearrange your HTML code. Move the `leftsidebar` div over the head like so:

```
<div class="leftsidebar">
    <div class="leftdiv">
    <div class="leftelement"> <h1>Left Div</h1></div>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="head">
    <div class="headelement">
    <h1>Head Div</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example:

```css
*{
    margin: 0%;
}
body{
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}



/* head div start */
.head{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
.headelement{
    background-color: rgb(115, 182, 240);
    height: auto;
}
/* head div end */



/* Left Side Bar Start */
.leftsidebar{
    display: flex;
}
.leftdiv{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
.leftelement{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(213, 233, 233);   
}
/* Left Side Bar end */



/* welcome div start  */
.welcomeDiv{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
.welcomeelement{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(193, 45, 196);
}
/* welcome div end  */



/* Inner 2 div start */
.innerdiv{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
.innerelement1{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(65, 225, 37); 
}
.innerelement2{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(226, 108, 23);
}
/* Inner 2 div end */



/* Footer div start */
.footerdiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.footerelement{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(132, 113, 122);
}
/* Footer div end */
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="leftsidebar">
        <div class="leftdiv">
            <div class="leftelement"> <h1>Left Div</h1></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="head">
            <div class="headelement">
                <h1>Head Div</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="welcomeDiv">
        <div class="welcomeelement"> 
            <h1>Welcome Div</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <div class="innerelement1">
            <h1>Inner no.1 div</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="innerelement2">
            <h1>Inner no.2 div</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerdiv">
        <div class="footerelement">
            <h1>Footer full width div </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just made it, and wow, Sir! As you said, it's worked magically. 
I don't have prior knowledge about it that's why I got stuck. But now I think I have a crystal clear concept about DIV for you! Thanks again and again.

Comment: Great! I am happy for you - I have decoded your question and found a solution. I am also not an expert and also learned something tonight. This is what Stackoverflow is for, right? Talented frontend devs are magicians for me :D I recommend https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction to you to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sir, and Stackoverflow is a good platform.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
position:relative; bottom:10px;
```

instead of

```
position absolute.
```

and see if it moves and add more pixels to `bottom:10px;` if needed. or try the `margin-bottom` property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately that's not worked.